# How to query scoped 'previous' and 'next' records (ActiveRecord & PostGres) rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, dynamic-queries

I am implementing something of a todo list with a user model and a List model with a date attribute.
On the user show page, I retrieve today's to do list.

How do I go about querying a user todo list for the previous and/or the next day.

All insights are welcome, thanks!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { self.username = username.downcase }
  has_many :to_do_lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[a-z_0-9]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :username, presence: true,
        format: { with: VALID_USERNAME_REGEX },
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  def name
     [first_name, last_name].compact.join(' ')
  end
end
```

and the list model

```
class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates :date, presence: true, 
        uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
end
```

Comment: It might help if you showed the model.

Answer (score 0):

Rails adds many helpful methods to `Time` to make this type of query quite intuitive. Since you validate that a user has only one to do list for each day:

```
 @next_day_list = @user.to_do_lists.find_by_date(Date.today.tomorrow)
 @prev_day_list = @user.to_do_lists.find_by_date(Date.today.yesterday)
```